# Efficient (repeat) looping

Tags: r

I am trying to evaluate if a price, price(k), in a given row,(k), is equal to the one above, price(k-1). If it is I want to sum the volume from the prior and the price in question, volume(k)+volume(k+1), and then remove the row with the duplicate price, row k.

I have the following repeat loop which I am applying to a large dataset looking to delete repeated values.

```
k <- 1
repeat{
if( Prices$Price[ k + 1 ] == Prices$Price[ k ] ){
Prices$CumVolume[ k + 1 ] <- Prices$CumVolume[ k + 1 ] + Prices$CumVolume[ k ] 
Prices <- Prices[ -k , ]
k <- k + 1
if( k > nrow( Prices ) ) break 
}
}
```

The loop is very slow and I was wondering if there are ways to speed it up. Unfortunately I am relatively new to R and am having difficulty working out the best way to go about this.

Also is there a way in R to observe the iteration the loop is currently up too? i.e. have it displayed in the workspace on each iteration?

Example data:

```
      Date         Time     Price     CumVolume Ret MeanRet VolRet
26 01-JAN-2009 21:30:01.783 96.660       537    0       0      0
31 01-JAN-2009 21:30:58.041 96.650        78    0       0      0
33 01-JAN-2009 21:34:09.589 96.640        60    0       0      0
35 01-JAN-2009 21:34:10.879 96.640        40    0       0      0
37 01-JAN-2009 21:35:55.001 96.635        50    0       0      0
```

Comment: Are u sure that the code is for "repeated values",can you give us some dummy example on what is expected output is ?

Comment: Yes. My apologies the initial if statement was missing from my original query.

Comment: did you see its output after a loop ? Means Prices data frame after repeat finished ?

Comment: Yes I did. But it is still very large ( 310,000 rows ).

Comment: But your k <- k + 1 & Break within the condition,if it will not find 2nd as duplicate ,it will go in infinite loop and if you are sure that the even index is always duplicate then what is the need of comparision ? show ur Prices[1:20,] data frame in question.

Comment: Could you amend the code as it should be? I am slightly confused. Are you saying k is not updating? or this loop will not stop?

Comment: Can you describe with *words*  what you are trying to achieve? It's not obvious from your code. Do you want to calculate the cumulative sum of `CumVolume` for each run of equal prices?

Comment: Roland, I am trying to evaluate if a price, price(k), in a given row,(k), is equal to the one above, price(k-1). If it is I want to sum the volume from the prior and the price in question, volume(k)+volume(k+1), and then remove the row with the duplicate price, row k.

Comment: Show the final result you want, not just the data at the start. This is especially important when your attempt at coding it doesn't work. I'm a bit concerned that you want to change the current CumVolume column rather than adding a new column with the meaning you're intending here. Also, dropping rows and losing those time stamps might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want something like this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="      Date         Time     Price     CumVolume Ret MeanRet VolRet
26 01-JAN-2009 21:30:01.783 96.660       537    0       0      0
31 01-JAN-2009 21:30:58.041 96.650        78    0       0      0
33 01-JAN-2009 21:34:09.589 96.640        60    0       0      0
35 01-JAN-2009 21:34:10.879 96.640        40    0       0      0
37 01-JAN-2009 21:35:55.001 96.635        50    0       0      0", header=TRUE)

#create a run id
DF$runs <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DF$Price) != 0))
#sum per each price run
DF$CCVolume <- with(DF, ave(CumVolume, runs, FUN=sum))
#remove duplicated prices
DF[!duplicated(DF$Price), ]
#          Date         Time  Price CumVolume Ret MeanRet VolRet runs CCVolume
#26 01-JAN-2009 21:30:01.783 96.660       537   0       0      0    1      537
#31 01-JAN-2009 21:30:58.041 96.650        78   0       0      0    2       78
#33 01-JAN-2009 21:34:09.589 96.640        60   0       0      0    3      100
#37 01-JAN-2009 21:35:55.001 96.635        50   0       0      0    4       50
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is going in infinite loop because of your increment index.`K=k+1`  and `Break` is always within the condition,I hope you want this

```
k=1
z=unique(Prices$Price)
for(i in 1:length(z))
{
     dupindex=which(z[i]==Prices$Price)
     Prices$CumVolume[tail(dupindex,n=1)]=sum(Prices$CumVolume[dupindex])
     Prices=Prices[-(dupindex[1:length(dupindex)-1]),]

}
```

I hope it help,thanks.